# Requiring a complex action before sharing externally

Tags: workflow, wizard, actions, complexity

This is my first post to UXStackExchange, so I apologize if I miss something or am too long.

I have been tasked with solving a complex problem for an internal enterprise app. We are working on creating shareable versions of the product via a link for our clients, but need to convert certain data sets to another format before allowing external access.

One of the functionalities that the product offers is doing a search, and saving results set as "collection" for later manipulation of results by refining search queries, applying different filters, etc. This search is the functionality we need to remove before giving external access because of the privacy of the data we hold.
Each search result "collection" needs to be manually converted to "groups of content", another type of data grouping functionality in our product, in order to avoid any access to any data we cannot share through search "collections".

And for technical reasons, it can not be done automatically - the user needs to go through a manual process of converting "collections" into "groups", with the freedom to add on or remove any data from the original collection set.

So the process, with my questions, doubts and dillemas, is:

1. User creates a search collection
2. User is informed this is fine but will need to be converted before sharing externally

   **2.1. Do I use a popup? A tooltip? A ribbon?**

   **2.2. Do I allow them to convert immediately, knowing that in that case, they will lose the functionality of manipulating the collection before actually sharing externally?**

   **2.3. Do I keep the message as a reminder at all times, or do I allow them to disregard it and not show again?**
3. User clicks on share externally
4. User is informed that EACH collection needs to be converted into a group

   **4.1. Is it better to use a ribbon, a popup, or jump straight to the conversion wizard?**

**5. How to make this wizard as delightful as possible, and as short as possible, while still providing all the requested functionality (ie. removing and adding results while converting)?**

**6. Finally, successfully finishing this process and getting a link that can be shared with clients.**

What bugs me is this long, tedious process (there are usually 3-6 collections in each project) that is unfortunately necessary. Not sure about the best moments to educate users and prepare them for what is to come, while at the same time avoiding being overwhelmed and just giving up.

For technical reasons, it can only be done this way, and it is my job to polish the hell out of that experience.

What we do have going for us is that this is an internal app, used by our employees, albeit not mandatory so opting out is still a very realistic scenario.

Let me know if any more details are needed, and sorry for the vagueness at times, I need to be careful around sharing details.

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your contribution to UXSE! As the question stands, there are a lot of details about the process you are describing, but not enough context (e.g. screenshots, mockups, persona or user information) to provide a more specific answer to the question. Also, there are lots of different questions combined into one which will also make the answers rather long and difficult to understand. If it is really not possible to provide the necessary details, I would suggest at least breaking down the question into a number of more generic questions (after searching for similar questions on UXSE).